# Kubectl apply: operation not permitted in Minikube

Tags: kubectl, minikube

I have a Minikube cluster and when I want to run `kubectl apply ./application.yaml` it responsds with `error: open ./application.yaml: operation not permitted`. How can I Solve it?

Comment: Try running the command  `kubectl apply -f ./application.yaml`  . I think you have missed -f

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?

Comment: Yeah, I had to enable permissions for my terminal on my operational system.

Comment: Please post the provided comment as a solution for the greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the error by enabling permissions for my terminal on my operational system.